# Improving this circuit from Texas Instruments note (inrush current)

Tags: mosfet, comparator, inrush-current

this is an example circuit in this [PDF from TI](https://www.ti.com/lit/slyy168). (page 19, inrush current stuff)

[image: Discrete Current-Limiting Circuit]

Description :

> In steady-state operation, Q1 is fully turned on and load current
> flows through the series sense resistor Rs and discrete power switch
> Q1. The voltage drop across Rs generates bias voltage VBE for Q2,
> which is used to control Q1 in a closed-loop form. When the load
> current reaches high enough to bias Q2 on, Q2 reduces the
> gate-to-source voltage of Q1 to limit the load current to VBE/Rs.
>
> The response time of this discrete approach is much better than a fuse
> or PTC, but still suffers from poor accuracy. Current-limiting
> accuracy can be in the range of 30% considering the variation of VBE
> voltage over temperature. Another disadvantage is the power loss in
> the sense resistor; for a 5-A application, dissipation would be as
> high as 3.25 W (0.65 V × 5 A = 3.25 W). **It is possible to reduce the
> power loss by using either a current-sense amplifier or a fast
> comparator to disable pass switch Q1 in the event of overload**, but
> this adds complexity and cost.

**How the suggested comparator would fit into this circuit?**

I don't know which op-amp pins would connect to which components here?
a summarized connections description (or schematic) helps a lot.

Thanks

Comment: [How to design high-side current sensing solutions using comparators](https://training.ti.com/how-design-high-side-current-sensing-solutions-using-comparators); [INA200 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/document-viewer/INA200/datasheet/application-and-implementation#SBOS3747142).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a difference amplifier across a sense resistor and then compare the difference voltage with a threshold, which corresponds to an overcurrent value. If overcurrent is detected you pull the PMOS gate to VIN to shut it off. This will lead to 'hiccup' conduction mode because, once the FET is off, the overcurrent state will auto-ckear. If you use an opamp to control the FET gate, you can also realize current saturation instead.

You can omit the difference amplifier if the sense resistor is directly attached to VIN or GND with one end. In this case, it is sufficient to compare to other end of the sense resistor to a reference voltage which is different from VIN or GND by the threshold amount.

Comment: I searched these concepts, and finally (with help from the video CL commented) I understand what you meant. except for this part _"If you use an opamp to control the FET gate, you can also realize current saturation instead."_ what you mean by "realize current saturation" ?

Comment: You set up an opamp such that it tries to keep the voltage across the sense resistor *equal* to the threshold voltage. If the load doesn't draw enough current, even with the gate at GND and the FET fully on, this cannot be realized. But when the load draws more current, the opamp will gradually close the FET to keep the current equal to the limit current.

Answer (score 1):

If you search TI (and Linear Technology, and Maxim) for high-side current monitors, you will find many parts.  One of these would replace Q2 (and Rs if it has a built-in shunt).  Because the IC has a true differential input with no minimum Vbe to overcome, the sense resistor can be much smaller.

Note:  This is a more complex circuit.  There is no direct, pin-for-pin translation to the circuit you posted.